# facebook like button wont work in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, google-chrome

im having some problems in google chrome, the site im developing is http://www.webjor.com.br/

the like button works fine in firefox, ie AND in anonymous chrome mode... but in regular chrome, after several cache/historic clean ups, the buttons simply dont appear anywhere! anyone now why this is happening? thanks!!

im using the regular html5 code that facebook gives, i really dont understand what is going on...

the div that englobes the fb button div is that one:

```
.fastmenu {
z-index:8;
margin-top:210px    !important;
margin-right:10px   !important;
}

.fastmenu .facebt {
width: 65px;
height: 65px;
text-align: right;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Have you disabled all extensions in chrome?

Comment: lol youre right, it was an extension blocking the facebook plugin! thanks dude! (why i cant mark your answer useful?)

Comment: What extension did you disable that was causing the issue?